# Delphi. подсчет строк в огромных файлах

Tags: delphi

Как правильно подсчитать строки в файлах 2 - 3 или 4 гигабайта.

Сделал вот так:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
list : TStringList;
begin
list := TstringList.Create;
list.LoadFromFile('test.txt');
ShowMessage('Количество строк = '+IntToStr(list.Count));
list.Free;
end;
```

Но на больших файлах не работает, загружает оперативную память. Как можно сделать лучше ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var
  f: TextFile;
  lineCount: integer;
begin
  AssignFile(f, 'test.txt');
  Reset(f);
  try
    while not Eof(f) do
    begin
      ReadLn(f);
      Inc(lineCount);
      if lineCount mod 1000 = 0 then
      begin
        // report progress
      end;
    end;
  finally
    CloseFile(f);
  end;
  ShowMessage('Количество строк = ' + IntToStr(lineCount));
```

Comment: Отличная реализация. Можно еще с буфером поиграться и увеличить скорость подсчета. В любом случае работает хоть и медленней но за то читает!

Comment: @Тарас Можно. Это решение - "в лоб".

Comment: Попробовал с буфером. То есть: в Var пишу Buf1: array [0 .. 4096 * 2 - 1] of Char; И далее после Reset(); Прописал System.SetTextBuf(f, Bf1); . Так где то в два раза быстрее.

Comment: емнип, где то тут или на английском СО был пост с замерами влияния разного размера буфера на скорость чтения. поищите. ну или так на практике попробуйте разные значения, мб кратные размеру кластера на диске. и не ограничивайтесь килобайтами, попробуйте и до 16мб например.